# Why is this exception not being caught by the rescue block?

Tags: ruby

I ran this code:

```
begin
  print 'Enter something:'
  x = gets.to_i          # Enter a string
rescue => err
  print(err.to_s)
end
```

I don't get why the rescue block does not catch the exception. It always
returns zero when a string is input, and doesn't trigger the rescue block. I don't know why it isn't working. Can anyone please help?

Comment: because `"any_string".to_i` => 0. `to_i` always return zero on strings that start with chars. `"123foo".to_i` => 123 for instance

Comment: Is the goal here to capture an error when non-numerical input is provided? If so, can you define the sorts of values that you consider valid? Like is `-2` valid? `-0`? `939249359434593459435934966`?

Comment: You might want to use something like [`x = Integer(gets.chomp)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) if you really want  an exception for non-numeric inputs.

Comment: @HolgerJust `Integer(gets)` is enough, trailing newline characters are ignored.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exception are you referring to when you say that it is not rescuing "this" exception? What is "this"? Honestly, I don't even see how that code *could* raise an exception. So, please be specific: *what* exception is raised?

Comment: The downvotes are unwarranted. This is a reasonable question, as the behavior of #to_i vs #Integer is not well understood by most Ruby newcomers.

Comment: @Stefan Not just trailing ones, either. `Integer "\n1\r" #=> 1`

Comment: Using `Integer()` as a safeguard for input is fine. But if dealing with non-numeric user input is a _normal_ situation in your program, it might be better to not use exceptions at all. You could for example use a regular expression instead to check whether the input contains only digits and print a message otherwise. This would allow you to use exceptions for the _exceptional_ situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Behavior Differs Between String#to_i and Kernel#Integer

The reason your exception handler is never called is because [String#to_i](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-to_i) doesn't raise an exception, even if it can't detect a valid integer within the String object. In such cases, it simply returns `0`.

In comparison, the behavior of [Kernel#Integer](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) is more complex, but is expected to raise ArgumentError or TypeError if the contents of the string do not strictly conform to a numeric representation.

So, to minimally refactor your existing code to raise an exception on non-numeric inputs:

```
begin
  print 'Enter something: ' 
  x = Integer gets
rescue => err
  # Do something other than just print err on STDERR, which is the 
  # default behavior anyway. Perhaps send it to STDOUT instead.
  puts "I received an exception: #{err}"

  # After handling, re-raise the original exception with or without
  # passing the original exception object. `raise` and `raise err` 
  # will do the same thing here.
  raise

  # For more advanced uses, you can also do something else like raise 
  # a different exception (e.g. TypeError), or modify the exception
  # object stored in err and raise that modified object instead.
end
```

The following user inputs will each convert cleanly:

- `1`
- `2`
- `0xff`

The code will even handle initial/trailing spaces, newlines, and carriage returns in most cases, without any additional effort on your part. However:

- > Enter something: one
  >   ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "one\n"
- > Enter something: "1"
  >   ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "\"1\"\n"
- > Enter something: nil
  >   ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "nil\n"

In general, you can rely on Kernel#Integer to raise an exception when necessary, which simplifies your code a lot. However, see caveats below.

### Caveats

These examples don't require it, but you might also want to sanitize your input with #strip, #chomp, or other string transformations when necessary. Your mileage in this regard will vary greatly with your real-world use case, but while Kernel#Integer generally does the right thing, and Ruby encourages relying on exceptions to handle non-standard edge cases, it's often unwise to trust user-tainted inputs.

It's also worth noting that both String#to_i and Kernel#Integer might operate on values other than user input, in which case know that `Integer(nil)` will raise:

> Integer nil
>   TypeError: can't convert nil into Integer

This might be important. Again, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Practical1 No thanks needed. Upvotes and accepted answers are the currency of appreciation on Stack Exchange. :) Comments are primarily for clarifications.

Comment: You can just call `raise` to re-raise the currently rescued exception. There's no need to pass it as an argument.

Comment: @Stefan You're right(ish). Raise by itself inside the rescue block will re-raise the original exception. However, it's not very explicit, and explicit helps new Rubyists. In fact, the OP's example only sends the exception to STDOUT instead of STDERR, so removing the rescue clause altogether makes more sense. There are also cases where raising a different exception or a modified exception after rescuing makes more sense than simply re-raising the original exception. I've expanded the explanation, but incorporating your point strays from the OP's original question about triggering rescue blocks.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs `$stdin.gets` and `$stdout.puts` would also be more explicit – I think simplicity helps a lot, too ;-) If the program has to deal with invalid user input in more sophisticated ways than merely failing, exception handling might not be the right tool in the first place.